# Eigenvalue of a $3\times 3$ complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, cayley-hamilton

In the following question I got that $0$ is not an eigenvalue, then $M$ is invertible and using Cayley-Hamilton then I got the last option correctly, then why given that $\alpha+\beta \neq 0$? What is the importance of that? Question is

Suppose that the characteristic equation of $M \in \mathbb{C}^{3 \times 3}$ is
$$
\lambda^{3}+\alpha \lambda^{2}+\beta \lambda-1=0
$$
where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha+\beta \neq 0$.
Which of the following statements is TRUE?
$$
M(I-\beta M)=M^{-1}(M+\alpha I)
$$
$$
M(I+\beta M)=M^{-1}(M-\alpha I)
$$
$$
M^{-1}\left(M^{-1}+\beta I\right)=M-\alpha I
$$
$$
M^{-1}\left(M^{-1}-\beta I\right)=M+\alpha I
$$

Comment: If $P(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I)-M),$ then $P(M)=0.$ In your case $M$ is invertible as $P(0)\neq 0.$ All identities are true, provided they can be transformed to $P(M)=0.$

Comment: ya you are correct. IN question given that (alpha+ beta) not equal to zero ,What is the significance of that, I am confused on that actually .Even if (alpha+ beta)  equal to zero M is invertible. Right?

Comment: It seems the assumption $\alpha +\beta \neq 0$ is irrelevant, unless you need some other properties of $M.$ I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this condition was used to ensure that the fourth equation was the unique solution.

If $\alpha=-1, \beta=1$ then the first equation is true.

If $\alpha=i, \beta=-i$ then the second equation is true.

If $\alpha=0, \beta=0$ then the third equation is true.

Thus $\alpha +\beta \ne 0$ prevents all of these possibilities.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda^{3}+\alpha \lambda^{2}+\beta \lambda-1=0$

The characteristic equation implies:

$M^3 + \alpha M^2 + \beta M - I = 0$

At which point is it basic algebra.

$M^3 + \alpha M^2 = I - \beta M\\
M^{-2}(M^3 + \alpha M^2) = M^{-2}(I - \beta M)\\
M + \alpha  = M^{-1}(M^{-1} - \beta)$

Comment: α+β≠0  is irrelevant right?